# Programmatically analyze a line graph

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, graph, analysis

I got a line graph with Y axis having value and X axis having time. The X axis have 5 minute resolution. I'm looking for **some kind of an algorithm to help me teach the iPhone to understand where the line is going**. I've never taken an algorithms class, so any help would be appreciated. What I need to know is if the line has been rising for a certain number of segments continuously.

Right now I'm implementing the following: 
If the current data point has Y value greater than the previous one, increment the slope counter by one. If it is equal, increment slope counter by 0. If the value is less, decrement the slope counter.

```
if(current>previous)
{
  counter++;
}
else if(current<previous)
{
  counter--;
}
```

This produces a sawtooth like graphs, which is easier to analyze. However due to the problems with the window size, the graph may "bounce". This is where I expect my logic to have problems.

I hope there's some kind of CS algorithm to help me with this task, as I don't even know what kinds of keywords to type into google for this problem.

Comment: by "bounce", do you mean the line hit the floor/ceiling and reflected back?  or they go off-scale?

Comment: by reading title and first half of your Q, the keywords that came to me was 'time series', 'trends',  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation , like that.  basically it reads time series data and try to guess where it is going or try to eliminate extra bounciness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to know is if the line has been rising for a certain number of segments continuously, why not just have a counter that increments until it hits that certain number of segments, or resets if the line goes down, like:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < datasize; i++) {
  if (data[i] > data[i - 1]) {
    ++counter;
    if (counter == THRESHOLD) {
      println("trending up at %d.", i);
    }
  } else if (data[i] < data[i - 1]) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

If you're just looking to see if the line is trending up or down overall, could you just do this:

```
if (data[datasize - 1] > data[0]) {
  println("Overall trend is up.");
} else if (data[datasize - 1] < data[0]) {
  println("Overall trend is down.");
} else {
  print("Overall trend is flat.");
}
```

If you want better prediction -- like, here's the line up to this point in time, here's a guess at what it's going to look like in the future, there are two avenues to explore. The first is "regression analysis" or "regression lines". This will work best for data which is generally increasing or decreasing as time goes on, and will get you the rate of those increases or decreases (the average slope of the line).

The second is "Fast Fourier Transform" - this is useful for lines which are like waves, in that they stay between a min and a max bound and have some regular cycle (or a number of regular cycles, which is what the equation will divine).

Have fun. This is an enjoyable problem to solve.

Comment: Another family of prediction algorithms includes things like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing - for which you might be able to just copy the formula and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter, which would take more work to implement.

Comment: Double exponential smoothing may help, although in my case, it may distort the measurement because it "overshoots". I'm already using Kalman filter somewhere else, I'll see how I can apply it to this problem.

Comment: The auto-incrementing counter code is very much like what I already have. One issue that I'm having with that is that visually, I can see when the graph is rising and has a slight irregularity (1 step down, 3 steps up, etc). This would reset the algorithm above. Double exp smoothing will smoothe it out, but my signal's peak is too unpredictable to correctly set the a and b values, iirc.

Comment: and yes, FFT is something that I've been looking at for a couple weeks now. It's an abyss. There's a need for correct window size, window function, it's a monster. Very hard to digest, even though I have the code to do FFT, without correct sampling rate there's infinite spectral spectral leakage to be really useful :(

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is [Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) , which is estimating a good straight line match to your data (in one least squares sense).  The slope of this line might help you tell "where it is going", depending on the behavior of the underlying model.